# Jenkins Build is failing with sql46010 incorrect syntax near IF while using "DROP TABLE IF EXIST #tempTable" ,

Tags: sql-server, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am drop a temp table before using it again in a SP by using "DROP TABLE IF EXIST #tempTable" statement. In SQL Server this is working fine, but when it pushed this code then jenkins build is failing saying sql46010 incorrect syntax near IF.
Any reason why and how can I resolve this?

Comment: The syntax is wrong (`EXIST` instead of `EXISTS`): `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tempTable`. If your actual statement is correct, then the SQL Server version of the target is older than SQL 2016 (when the `IF EXISTS` clause was added to `DROP TABLE`).

Comment: Sorry actual statement is correct (IF EXISTS) .
What's the alternative for that?

Comment: You can use an IF statement instead of IF clause when you need to support pre-SQL Server 2016: `IF(OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#tempTable','U') IS NOT NULL) DROP TABLE #tempTable;`

Comment: But a local temp table created within a procedure doesn't need to be dropped - that happens automatically at the end of the procedure execution. Here you appear to have applied a pattern of dropping temp tables at the beginning of a stored procedure - why? Stop doing that - problem solved.